# Creating a new column with more rows in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I think I should edit the example since it is misleading. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

The following is an example of the warning that I faced with:

```
dsf <- data.table(v1=c('a','a','b','b','b','c'),v2=c(3,5,8))
> dsf
   v1 v2
1:  a  3
2:  a  5
3:  b  8
4:  b  3
5:  b  5
6:  c  8
```

I want to add a new column to produce

```
   v1 v2  v3
1:  a  3  5 
2:  a  5  7
3:  NA NA 4
4:  b  8  6
5:  b  3  9
6:  b  5  4
7:  NA NA 4
8:  c  8  7
9:  NA NA 9
```

but I get a warning message like:

> In `[.data.table`(dsf, , `:=`(v3, c(1:4))) :
>     Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'v3' (1 unused)

and the data table as:

```
   v1 v2  v3
1:  a  3  5 
2:  a  5  7
3:  b  8  6
4:  b  3  9
5:  b  5  4
6:  c  8  7
```

In the original case - that I am working on - I have something like this:

```
dsf <- dsf[, v3:=f(list(v2)) , by=list(v1)]
```

The function f creates an extra value.

Comment: good discussion: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Adding-collumn-to-existing-data-frame-td2312788.html

Comment: @Mike H. I have edited the example, thank you.

Comment: @CPak I have edited the example, thank you, too.

Comment: How do you know you where you want to add `NA`s? For example, why is there a `NA` in the 3rd and 7th row? Shouldn't they all be at the end if you want to do something like `dsf$v3 <- c(5,7,4,6,9,4,4,7,9)`?

Comment: @Mike H. In dsf <- dsf[, v3:=f(list(v2)) , by=list(v1)] the function f uses all of the values of v2 with respect to the grouping by by=list(v1). And produces values with one extra.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a `cbind.fill` function from the `rowr` package that could be useful:

```
data.table(rowr::cbind.fill(dsf, data.table(v3 = c(1:4)), fill = NA))
#   v1 v2 v3
#1:  a  3  1
#2:  a  5  2
#3:  b  8  3
#4: NA NA  4
```

Alternatively, you could try merging the two together. Something like:

```
dsf2 <- dsf[,rows := 1:nrow(dsf)][data.table(v3=c(1:4), rows = 1:4), on = .(rows)][,rows := NULL]
dsf2
#   v1 v2 v3
#1:  a  3  1
#2:  a  5  2
#3:  b  8  3
#4: NA NA  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
myfun <- function(df, vec) {
    L <- c(as.list(df), v3 = list(vec))
    result <- lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L)))
    do.call(cbind.data.frame, result)
}

myfun(dsf, 1:4)

    # v1 v2 v3
# 1    a  3  1
# 2    a  5  2
# 3    b  8  3
# 4 <NA> NA  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, my answer is not good looking, but this is enough for me ...
Thanks to Stack Overflow :)

```
dsf <- data.table(v1=c('a','a','b','b','b','c'),v2=c(3,5,8))

dsf2 <- unique(as.data.frame(dsf[,1]))
dsf2$v2 <- NA

dsf <- rbind(dsf,dsf2)
dsf <- arrange(dsf,v1)
dsf <- dsf[, v3:=c(1:length(v2)), by=list(v1)]
>dsf
   v1 v2 v3
1:  a  3  1
2:  a  5  2
3:  a NA  3
4:  b  8  1
5:  b  3  2
6:  b  5  3
7:  b NA  4
8:  c  8  1
9:  c NA  2
```